# running selenium tests from command line junit

Tags: java, selenium, command-line, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to execute selenium tests(JUNIT) from command line

my project folder path class file

```
C:\Users\CP042756\workspace\BLR_demo1\bin\com\analytics\logindash
```

File :LoginTest.class

my project folder path java file

```
C:\Users\CP042756\workspace\BLR_demo1\src\com\analytics\logindash
```

File:LoginTest.java

jar file folder: `C:\jars\imp\selenium-2.45.0\libs`

jar fiLe: `junit-dep-4.11.jar`

it runs properly in Eclipse

i want to run it in command line

i have tried the following commands from the command line

```
1)
java -cp C:\jars\imp\selenium-2.45.0\libs\junit-dep-4.11.jar:C:\Users\CP042756\workspace\BLR_demo1\bin\com\analytics\logindash org.junit.runner.JUnitCore LoginTest
```

Error:Could not find or load main class

```
2)java -cp C:\jars\imp\selenium-2.45.0\libs\junit-dep-4.11.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore LoginTest
```

Error:Could not find class:Login test
Exception in thread main java.lang.noclassdefounderror

Please help,

Comment: I suggest using a build tool like maven or gradle. They handle these details for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use semicolon as path separator in Windows. Then your first example should work.

For class files there are [two different rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). check, which one applies to your situation:

> For .class files in an unnamed package, the class path ends with the
>   directory that contains the .class files. For .class files in a named
>   package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the
>   "root" package (the first package in the full package name).

So, for the latter try this:

```
java -cp C:\jars\imp\selenium-2.45.0\libs\junit-dep-4.11.jar;C:\Users\CP042756\workspace\BLR_demo1\bin org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.analytics.logindash.LoginTest
```

Comment: yes tried but Error:Could not find class:Login test Exception in thread main java.lang.noclassdefounderror

Comment: yes i did some research on that  don't no where i am missing stuck up badly and tried like this same error java -cp C:\jars\imp\selenium-2.45.0\libs\junit-dep-4.11.jar;C:\Users\CP042756\workspace\BLR_demo1 org.junit.runner.JUnitCore LoginTest Error:Could not find class:Login test

Comment: See my answer. **Full package name**: com.analytics.logindash.LoginTest

Comment: yes i tried that too java -cp C:\jars\imp\selenium-2.45.0\libs\junit-dep-4.11.jar;C:\Users\CP042756\workspace\BLR_demo1\bin\com\analytics\logindash org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  com.analytics.logindash.LoginTest **Error: could not find class com.analytics.logindash.LoginTest **

Comment: See my answer. **class path ends with the directory...** In your case the second cp should end on **bin** not on **logindash**

Comment: thanks for your help sir. but no help i tried it all 1) java -cp C:\jars\imp\selenium-2.45.0\libs\junit-dep-4.11.jar;C:\Users\CP042756\workspace\BLR_demo1 org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  com.analytics.logindash.LoginTest
2)
java -cp C:\jars\imp\selenium-2.45.0\libs\junit-dep-4.11.jar;C:\Users\CP042756\workspace\BLR_demo1\bin org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  com.analytics.logindash.LoginTest